# Ubuntu version with lesser system requirement

Tags: dual-boot

I am planning to dual-boot Ubuntu 16.04 using Universal USB Installer in my machine. However, Ubuntu 16.04 recommends having 3.2 GHz clock speed or better; my machine only has 2.4 GHz. Is there a version of Ubuntu that requires a minimum of 2.4 GHz? And how can I download the iso file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found on the ubuntu homepage ([Ubuntu Help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)) that since ubuntu 11.04 you need 1000 ΜHz processor, 1024 MiB RAM, 3D Acceleration Capable Videocard with at least 256 MB. So your system should be googd enough.

If you want to install something smaller try Xubuntu or Lubuntu instead which only need 512 MiB of system memory (RAM).

Personally I use Ubuntu 16.04 on an old dell notebook together with Windows7 without any problems.

My System: old Dell, Intel Core i7 CPU Q720 @ 1.60 GHz, Grafic: AMD RV730 and 4 GB RAM

Comment: To download the ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS iso file use : [link](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso)

Comment: Add some of your hardware-specs like cpu-frequency, RAM-amount. Probably you use a graphics-card, then you should mention that and add the specs of it too. Adding the specs will make it easy for the OP to compare with his own machine.

Comment: Adding this information to your answer by clicking `edit` (below your answer) would be perfect...